# Hadoop streaming and log4j

Tags: hadoop, log4j

I have a Hadoop streaming job which fails for some reason. To find out why this happens I found corresponding stderr of the failed task, but there is only message about log4j not initialized:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Referenced website says that this means, default configuration files log4j.properties and log4j.xml can not be found and the application performs no explicit configuration.
I my system log4j.properties file is located in the usual ${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop/ directory. Why Hadoop cannot find it? Is this because streaming job is not supposed to log via log4j anyways?.. Is it possible to see stdout/stderr of a streaming job written in e.g. Perl?

Thanks!